# opencv: TypeError: mask is not a numerical tuple

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Hey I am getting error `TypeError: mask is not a numerical tuple` when trying to add scalar to a matrix while using a mask. The mask variable is printed here:

```
(15.0, array([[  0, 255,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       ..., 
       [255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255, ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8))
```

And this is the error itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clime/mrak/motionpaint/motion_painter.py", line 97, in process_frame
    self.alphas = cv2.add(self.alphas, self.alpha_increment, mask=mask)
TypeError: mask is not a numerical tuple
```

This is how I get the mask:

```
    diff = cv2.absdiff(self.prevFrame, smoothedFrame)

    # convert difference to grayscale.
    greyDiff = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # grayscale to black and white (i.e. false and true)
    mask = cv2.threshold(greyDiff, self.threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add), `mask` needs to be an "8-bit single channel array".  Your mask is not.

Here is a small working example of using cv2.add with a mask:

```
In [43]: import cv2, numpy
In [44]: src1 = numpy.ones((5, 5), dtype=numpy.uint8)
In [45]: src2 = numpy.ones((5, 5), dtype=numpy.uint8)
In [46]: mask = numpy.ones((5, 5), dtype=numpy.uint8)
In [47]: mask[0, 0] = 0
In [48]: cv2.add(src1, src2, None, mask )
Out[48]: 
array([[0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], dtype=uint8)
```

#### Using threshold to create a mask

According to the [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold), the function `cv2.threshold` returns a tuple, the second element of which is a mask.  So, use:

```
retval, mask = cv2.threshold(src1, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: But what is my mask then? I updated my question with a piece of code that constructs the mask.

Comment: Oh I see that now. It is a tuple where the first elem is retval. So I need to do `retval, mask = cv2.threshold ...` Not sure what retval means there though

Comment: @clime The documentation is weak on that but, normally, a `retval` of zero means success and a non-zero value indicates failure.